# difference between `iterate` and `repeatedly`

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to clojure/clojurescript and trying to figure out why this function always returns 100 as the first random integer and a few zeros at the end:

```
(take 10 (iterate rand-int 100))
;; (100 30 19 15 4 3 2 0 0 0)
```

But this works as expected:

```
(take 10 (repeatedly #(rand-int 100)))
;; (14 14 16 92 10 69 85 74 65 95)
```

But then if I use anonymous fn with `iterate` I get `nil` as first value but the rest looks OK:

```
(take 10 (iterate #(rand-int 100)))
;; (nil 27 19 76 70 40 63 72 32 55)
```

Comment: You must have a typo in your 3rd example; I get:  `ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/iterate  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)`

Comment: @AlanThompson, It's not a typo but rather my lack of knowledge. However it does work in `lumo` repl for me with a warning: `WARNING: Wrong number of args (1) passed to cljs.core/iterate at line 1
(nil 6 76 80 37 10 88 15 38 60)`

Comment: @AlanThompson Note the question is about cljs, and you tried it on the JVM, which has stricter ideas about what is a reasonable way to call a function. The way that javascript handles missing arguments is (roughly) to pretend they were nil, and excess arguments are ignored. So the third example is really `(take 10 (iterate (fn [_] (rand-int 100)) nil))`, and it's clear that will behave exactly the way this question reports.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`iterate` returns the sequence `(x (f x) (f (f x)) ...)` so the first element is the `100` you provide. The second element is the result of `(rand-int 100)` which returns a random number in the range `(0, 99]`. In this case it returned `30` so the third element is the result of `(rand-int 30)` which returns an element in the range `(0, 29]`. Since the range is reducing, the generated numbers rapidly approach 0.

In contrast `repeatedly` returns the sequence `((f) (f) (f)...)` where `f` is a function of no arguments like `#(rand-int 100)` where the range of generated numbers is always `(0, 99]`. `f` is expected to have some side-effect (modifying the state of the random number generator)

Comment: Awesome. I did read the documentation but didn't quite understand it. You said it very clear. Thanks.